# Add to array A the difference of array A and B

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Assuming I have 2 arrays :

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I need `a` to have the difference from `b`
so `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Is there a cleaner or more performant way than

`a.concat(b.filter(x => !a.includes(x)))` ?

Comment: `Is there a cleaner way than` - by "cleaner" do you mean a way that actually produces the required result? since that code produces `[1,2,3,[4,5]]` - not the result you require

Comment: `more performant` - are you dealing with arrays with hundreds of thousands of elements? if not, then *performant* isn't an issue (unless you're running on a steam powered 80286 or something

Comment: @Bravo just noticed it, edited

Comment: Could use  a Set to return the unique values `a= [...new Set( a.concat(b))]`

Comment: If you truly want performance, which I don't think is a big concern nowadays, then steer clear of array functions and use loops.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir can you explain why it iterates `b` more than once in my case ?, is it the concat ?